# Не получается подгрузить стили через WebPack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, scss, sass

Я пытаюсь подключить шрифты на WebPack но он их не видит. Скачал шрифты, настроил sass и css, но шрифты не подгружает. не могу понять в чем проблема

вот конфиг моего WebPack

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const FileManagerPlugin = require('filemanager-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'), 
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    assetModuleFilename: path.join('images', '[name].[ext]'), 
  },
     module: {
         rules: [
           {
             test: /\.js$/, 
             use: 'babel-loader',
             exclude: /node_modules/,
           },
           {
            test:/\.pug$/, 
            loader:'pug-loader',
           },
           {
            test:/\.(scss|css)$/,
            use:[
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader',
                'sass-loader']
           },
           {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
           },
           {
            test:/\.svg$/,
            type:'asset/resource',
            generator: {
              filename: path.join('icons', '[name].[ext]'),
            },
           },
           {
            test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
          },
         ],
       },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'template.pug'),
      filename: 'index.html', 
    }),
    new FileManagerPlugin({
               events: {
                 onStart: { delete: [
                    {
                      source: './dist',
                      options: {
                        force: false,
                      },
                    },
                  ]},
               },
             }),
             new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
               filename: '[name].css', 
             }),
            ],
  devServer: {
    watchFiles: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 
    port: 9000, 
  },
  optimization: {
         minimizer: [
           new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
             minimizer: {
               implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
               options: {
                 plugins: [
                   ['gifsicle', { interlaced: true }],
                   ['jpegtran', { progressive: true }],
                   ['optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
                   ['svgo', { name: 'preset-default' }],
                 ],
               },
             },
           }),
         ],
       },
     };
```

стили загружены в src/fonts
в этой же папке находится fonts.scss

```
/* denk-one-regular - cyrillic-ext_latin_latin-ext */
@font-face {
     font-display: swap; /* Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display for other options. */
     font-family: 'Denk One';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     src: url('./denk-one-v17-cyrillic-ext_latin_latin-ext-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
     src: url('./denk-one-v17-cyrillic-ext_latin_latin-ext-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
          url('./denk-one-v17-cyrillic-ext_latin_latin-ext-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
          url('./denk-one-v17-cyrillic-ext_latin_latin-ext-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
          url('./denk-one-v17-cyrillic-ext_latin_latin-ext-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
          url('./denk-one-v17-cyrillic-ext_latin_latin-ext-regular.svg#DenkOne') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
   }
```

так же в корневой папке src лежит index.js

```
import './main.scss';
import './fonts/fonts.scss';

function component(text) {
    const element = document.createElement('h1');
    element.textContent = text;
    return element;
  }
  
  document.body.prepend(component('Проект собран на Webpack'));
```

все собирается.
если задаю в ручную какие либо стили, отрабатывает. а шрифты не грузит хоть убей.

Comment: Что означает фраза "задаю в ручную какие либо стили, отрабатывает" - эти "какие либо стили" имеют отношение к шрифтам? Что означает фраза "шрифты не грузит" - как конкретно вы пытаетесь грузить шрифты и как определили, что не грузит? Значение font-family правильное? В браузерном мониторинге сети видно хоть что-нибудь про шрифты?

Comment: в ручную добавляю стили означает, что если я захожу в fonts.scss и делаю
html{color:red;}
код отрабатывает.
так же если через F12 проверяю font-family то пишет что стиль задан правильно 'Denk One'
Но он не может найти путь к файлам шрифта и не подгружает их. пишет:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение проблемы. Ломаются шрифты при сборке.
`assetModuleFilename: path.join('images', '[name].[ext]'),`
заменил на

```
  `assetModuleFilename: 'images/[name][ext]',`
```

так же решил проблему с отчисткой директории которая собирается после команды

> npm run serve,
> npm run build, npm run dev

Корень директории

> dist

заменил

```
 onStart: { delete: [
                {
                  source: './dist',
                  options: {
                    force: false,
                  },
                },
              ]},
```

на

```
onStart: { 
              delete: [
              {
                source: path.join(__dirname,'dist/').replaceAll('\\','/'), 
                 options:{
              force: true,
              recursive : true,
             },
             },
        ]},
```

Comment: вопросы и ответы можно редактировать, не дублируйте сообщения, когда можно обойтись правками

Comment: благодарю. недавно только начал активничать на форуме

Comment: здесь не совсем форум, а база знаний "вопрос-ответ", именно на этот формат ориентируйтесь: один вопрос, под ним один или несколько ответов.